# PHP cURL download file by browser

Tags: php, curl, browser, download, filesize

Im create script to download file from some file server but not work perfectly.

```
        function downloadPage2($url){

        $ch = curl_init();
        $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 8096);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $buffer) {

            header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
            header('Cache-Control: private', false);
            header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mp3.mp3"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
//          header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($buffer)); // provide file size
            header('Connection: close');
            echo $buffer;
              return strlen($buffer);
            });
        curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

And when type $url to file (mp3) from server its download this file but not right filesize. Example: File on server has size 4.5mb and my script downloaded it but size is 6mb. Music is playing but interrupts per second.
Do you know where is a problem?

I tried set content-lenght in header but every function return content lengh = 0

Comment: ` Do you need to set all those options though?

Comment: I dont know, I tested all option and o dont now which is right :D ..  coockie is required

Comment: see updated answer below, add header options you need, that should give a starting point. Every server requirement are different, you just have to troubleshoot you way to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me download large files

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// if https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
// or set this option
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);
$file = $data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (file_exists($file)) {
  header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sometrack.mp3"');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  readfile($file);
} else {
  echo "no file";
}
```

Comment: But I dont want download file on disk on my server but make it with browser. Normalny like  user click 'download' on website and get popup with file.

Comment: sorry, kinda jumped the gun and did provide wrong answer to your question,  updated my answer.

Comment: I add setopt with cookie and its work. But ... First script download all file bytes to cache and then return popup to user to save. We dont want wait a lot of time as server (script) download file. Script must stream file in realtime.

Comment: check my updated answer, I did remove file download. that should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine with me, I am using php `readfile` function to read the file from a remote host as per documentation for `readfile`:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen_wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

```
        header('Content-Type:'.$this->get_mime_type($url));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
        echo readfile($url);


 function get_mime_type($filename) {
    $idx = explode( '.', $filename );
    $count_explode = count($idx);
    $idx = strtolower($idx[$count_explode-1]);

    $mimet = array(
        'txt' => 'text/plain',
        'htm' => 'text/html',
        'html' => 'text/html',
        'php' => 'text/html',
        'css' => 'text/css',
        'js' => 'application/javascript',
        'json' => 'application/json',
        'xml' => 'application/xml',
        'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
        'flv' => 'video/x-flv',

        // images
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
        'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
        'ico' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
        'tiff' => 'image/tiff',
        'tif' => 'image/tiff',
        'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
        'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',

        // archives
        'zip' => 'application/zip',
        'rar' => 'application/x-rar-compressed',
        'exe' => 'application/x-msdownload',
        'msi' => 'application/x-msdownload',
        'cab' => 'application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed',

        // audio/video
        'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
        'qt' => 'video/quicktime',
        'mov' => 'video/quicktime',

        // adobe
        'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
        'psd' => 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
        'ai' => 'application/postscript',
        'eps' => 'application/postscript',
        'ps' => 'application/postscript',

        // ms office
        'doc' => 'application/msword',
        'rtf' => 'application/rtf',
        'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
        'docx' => 'application/msword',
        'xlsx' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'pptx' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',


        // open office
        'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
        'ods' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    );

    if (isset( $mimet[$idx] )) {
        return $mimet[$idx];
    } else {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
}
```